# css selectors nth-child - to target first (n) children

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to target only the first four list items in the  using css selector nth-child and/or nth-last-child

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello first item</li>
    <li>Hello item 2<li>
    <li>Hello item 3</li>
    <li>Hello   item 4</li>
    <li>Hello  item 5</li>
    <li>Hello   item 6</li>
    <li>Hello   item 7</li>
    <li>Hello  item 8</li>
    <li>Hello  item 9</li>
</ul>
```

my first try:

```
ul li:nth-child(1n):not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Yet i wanted to simplify it

so my second one:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+4){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Can you tell me if there is any better solution than second one / is this the right way to target first (n) children ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Or is that just a typo? If you fix the typo it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GTuzM/

Comment: Wow, sharp eye @j08691! But Yes, this is indeed how you would do this with an nth-child selector.

Answer (score 19):

Your code works if you fix the typo:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GTuzM/)**

Although a better solution may be:

```
 ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V4QjC/)**

Comment: Thanks @j08691 yes that was a typo and i would go with solution 2.

Answer (score 1):

A simple css-way is:

```
li:not( :nth-child( 4 ) ~ li )
{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Explanation:

1. Set an anchor on the last element to be marked.
   `:nth-child( 4 )`

- Hello first item
- Hello item 2
- Hello item 3
- **Hello item 4**
- Hello item 5
- Hello item 6
- Hello item 7
- Hello item 8
- Hello item 9

2. All subsequent siblings are now to be marked.
   `:nth-child( 4 ) ~ li`

- Hello first item
- Hello item 2
- Hello item 3
- Hello item 4
- **Hello item 5**
- **Hello item 6**
- **Hello item 7**
- **Hello item 8**
- **Hello item 9**

3. Last it is still negated.
   `:not( :nth-child( 4 ) ~ li )`

- **Hello first item**
- **Hello item 2**
- **Hello item 3**
- **Hello item 4**
- Hello item 5
- Hello item 6
- Hello item 7
- Hello item 8
- Hello item 9

Et voilà.