# Trying to execute a for loop within the page.evaluate() function - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am currently using Puppeteer to scrape a web page. The web page specifically has div elements of `nth-child` that I am trying to iterate through. Without a for-loop I can successfully retrieve the `innerText` of a `div.ticker` element but if I add a for-loop to retrieve the `innerText` of multiple `div.ticker` elements, then the code within for-loop fails to execute and instead jumps straight to line 11. No errors are surfacing upon execution which is making me struggle to find why my for-loop is not executing.

```
 let scrapeData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
      let element = document.querySelector("#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > div.ticker").innerText;
      console.log(element);
    }

    return {
      element
    }
  });
  console.log("Hello world!");
  await browser.close();

  return scrapeData;
}
```

Comment: FYI those `console.log`s will show in the browser console not stdout.

Answer (score 2):

The `element` in return statement is not defined. You are declaring the `element` in the for loop scope and it's destroyed after the loop ends.

If there are multiple elements use array and push elements. But What you should really do is us `querySelectorAll` without the loop.

Comment: You're right, I forget that `let` is block-scoped. Unfortunately after defining `element` outside the for-loop, Puppeteer is still not executing the for-loop. 

For `querySelectorAll`, how can I limit it so that the method only selects the first 20 matching elements? Would it still need a loop since I need to iterate through every matching element on the page until reaching 20?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140514/css-selectors-nth-child-to-target-first-n-children
This is how you can select multiple children.
Have you tried putting debbuger statement inside the loop or console.log to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I left my `console.log(element);` statement in the for-loop inside to  see if the loop is being executed or not. I also set a breakpoint at `let scrapeData = await page.evaluate(() => {` and when I step over to the next line, it immediately skips over the for-loop.